# Handling IF condtions in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a query that based on various ids within a table should return different results.. So for example:

### Table 'orders'

- product_id
- item_id
- extra_id
- something_id

I'd like return a result based on the values of these, such as

```
IF item_id != 0 'ITEM' ELESEIF product_id != 0 'PRODUCT', etc.
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CASE expression is ANSI, supported on numerous databases:

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN o.item_id != 0 THEN 'ITEM'
         WHEN o.product_id != 0 THEN 'PRODUCT'
       END AS your_column_name
  FROM ORDERS o
```

ANSI is preferred for the portability, rather than native vendor syntax where possible.

Comment: Thank you, both methods worked, but I've also read this is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT IF (item_id <> 0,'ITEM',IF (product_id <> 0, 'PRODUCT','N/A')) as type
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html